# Нужно помощь с логикой инстанцирования объектов

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня цель задачи такая:  с конкретной позиции каждые 5 секунд создать объект, двигать его вниз и затем удалять.

Написал такой скрипт:

```
public GameObject columnPrefab; 
private Vector2 objectPoolPosition = new Vector2(0,900);
private float timeSinceLastSpawned;
public float spawnRate = 3f;   
public GameObject SimpleObject; 


void Start () {

    timeSinceLastSpawned = 0f;
//  InvokeRepeating ("InstantiateObject", 5f,2f);
}

public Transform target;

public float speed;
public void InstantiateObject()
{

    SimpleObject = (GameObject)Instantiate(columnPrefab, objectPoolPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    SimpleObject.transform.SetParent (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Canvas").transform, false);
}


void Update()
{
    timeSinceLastSpawned += Time.deltaTime;

    float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
    if (timeSinceLastSpawned >= spawnRate) { 

        InstantiateObject ();
        SimpleObject.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (SimpleObject.transform.position, target.position, step);
        timeSinceLastSpawned = 0f;
    }
}
```

Но движение не происходит, так как выходит из условия, пробовал Invoke и флагами ловить запускать, не получилось, движение происходит и как только выходит из условия `(timeSinceLastSpawned >= spawnRate)` движение прекращается и создается новый объект, подскажите как реализовать задуманное без костылей ?

Comment: Vector3.MoveTowards должен вызываться постоянно, а не один раз, как это сделано у вас. Вынесите его за условие.

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать вашу логику и только подправить, то вот

```
    void Update()
    {
        timeSinceLastSpawned += Time.deltaTime;
        float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
       if (timeSinceLastSpawned >= spawnRate) 
       { 
           Destroy(SimpleObject);
           InstantiateObject ();
           timeSinceLastSpawned = 0f;
       }
       SimpleObject.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (SimpleObject.transform.position, target.position, step);
    }
```

А вообще, зачем вы каждый раз создаете и убиваете один и тот же объект? Просто создайте его один раз (например, в start() ) и каждые пять секунд меняйте его позицию на начальную, это можно сделать как у вас - считать Time.deltaTime, а можно [запустить (один раз) корутину](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html), и каждые пять секунд ([yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html)) менять позицию на начальную, а в Update() просто движение вниз.